Sterility of man in Vedic times
So within dharmashastras, it is generally accepted that the man may marry a second time without abandoning the first wife if she doesn't produce sons or is infertile, but if the man is infertile and cannot produce an heir can the woman remarry with another man to produce children, please give direct references. I know in general men and women are not to marry someone who looks sick or genetically abnormal.
